# How to parallel process with Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, api, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

So I've been trying to create a parallel processing effect on the same file through different sources. Parallel processing in sound engineering is essentially when you duplicate a signal twice and apply different effects to each signal (ex. if I want a delay to only work on the lower end, then i'd duplicate the signal and add a biQuad with a lower boost + then an echo to only that signal, but not the original signal).

Right now I have the same file identified through different audio variables

```
var mainVerse = document.getElementById('audio1');
var mainVerseParallel = document.getElementById('audio2');
```

Where audio1 and audio2 point to the same source. I also have two sources for each file

```
var source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(mainVerse);
var source2 = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(mainVerseParallel);
```

I then apply the filters to each node

```
var s = source;
var s2 = source2;

 source.disconnect(audioCtx.destination);
source2.disconnect(audioCtx.destination);

for (var i in filters1) {
 s.connect(filters1[i]);
 s = filters1[i];
}


for (var i in filters2) {
 s2.connect(filters2[i]);
 s2 = filters2[i];
}

s.connect(audioCtx.destination);
s2.connect(audioCtx.destination);
```

But the when i play the audio files :

```
mainVerseParallel.play();
mainVerse.play();
```

They don't sync up properly, I've tried;

```
audio.addEventListener("canplaythrough", function, false)
```

but it gives a different sound every time I restart the track. Is there a way to fix this syncing issue, or is there a way i can do the parallel processing effect where I don't need  to create two audio variables and two sources?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two separate sources to split the signal path.

```
var s = source;
var s2 = source;
//       ^^^^^^ NOTE: not using source2

for (var i in filters1) {
    s.connect(filters1[i]);
    s = filters1[i];
}

for (var i in filters2) {
    s2.connect(filters2[i]);
    s2 = filters2[i];
}

s.connect(audioCtx.destination);
s2.connect(audioCtx.destination);
```